# Wordpress adding a menu page when activating a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Im making a custom plugin for wordpress and i need to create a page in the admin menu. I already have a file called mailing_list.php with the following code:

```
function jps_mail_list_page_entry() {
add_menu_page(
    __('JPS Mailing List'),
    'JPS Mailing List',
    'manage_options',
    'jpsNews_mailinglist',
    'jpsNews_mailing_list',
    'dashicons-email'
);
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'jps_mail_list_page_entry');


function jpsNews_mailing_list() {
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Now, in the plugin page i have this:

```
function jpsNews_activate_plugin() {
    include_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'pages/mailing-list.php');
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'jpsNews_activate_plugin');
```

Its not working so, is it even possible to do it like this? how can i do it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have anything in your server logs ?

Comment: no i dont. not that i see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have purposely added the function for the echo 'hello', but that's going to echo hello in the content area of the plug-in page.

For your mailing-list.php

```
function jps_mail_list_page_entry() {
   add_menu_page(
        __('JPS Mailing List', 'jpsNews_mailinglist' ),
        'JPS Mailing List',
        'manage_options',
        'jpsNews_mailinglist',
        'jpsNews_mailing_list',
        'dashicons-email'
   );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'jps_mail_list_page_entry');
```

for the plug-in page, you can simply do:

```
include_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/pages/mailing-list.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. turns out the function to add the pages must be outside the other functions. just put theme at the end of the script outside the activation hook and it worked.

```
// DISPLAY PAGES AND SUBPAGES
function jps_mail_list_page_entry() {
    add_menu_page(
        __('JPS Mailing List'),
        'JPS Mailing List',
        'manage_options',
        'jpsNews_mailinglist',
        'jpsNews_mailing_list',
       'dashicons-email'
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'jps_mail_list_page_entry');


function jpsNews_mailing_list() {
    include_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'pages/mailing-list.php');
}
```

Anyway, Thanks =)